# Highlighted processes on top

Tags: process, top

I am running four processes in two computers, a master node and a slave node. I gave the command to spawn these processes, while on `screen` command. Now, I logged into with ssh, in both computers and I can see that running processes in the master node are highlighted (as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613636/why-are-some-processes-highlighted-in-top) question states), while the running ones are not (and there seems to be no toggling done):

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: What's the version of top on both systems? Also, the link you provide contains a way of toggling the highlighting.

Comment: @the_Seppi 8.0 and 6.0.10. That should be the case, right? You could answer if so.

Comment: Does pressing `y` inside top switch the highlighting on?

Comment: Only in the 8.0 version. It does however affect both.

Comment: What affects both what?

Comment: Pressing `y`. It will switch the highlight on or off, but it will affect both tops. In the 8.0, it will also work as a switch.

Comment: So pressing `y` is the actual solution?

Comment: No @the_Seppi. In geomcomp, where no highlighting exists in my question, pressing `y` won't bring the light ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in a comment, the server is running top 8.0, while the client only is on 6.0.10.

It may well be possible that the highlighting was only added somewhere between those two versions, in which case it is simply not implemented in the version of your client OS.

Another solution may be something marginally mentioned in the question you linked to: The highlighting can be toggled on by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>. If it is implemented in your client, try it.